# Very few threads in the thread pool of threadpoolexcecutor actively executing tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `corePoolSize` = `maxPoolSize` = `queueSize` = `15`

Every incoming request spawns 7 tasks, to be executed with this thread pool.

Even though each of the individual tasks, on being scheduled, take less than 3 seconds, the overall request takes much longer.

I suspected that the system is falling short of threads and tasks being queued.

I logged the following information for every incoming request.

```
getActiveCount()
getLargestPoolSize()
getPoolSize()
getQueue().size()
```

I notice that the system is not falling short of threads.

`getPoolSize` and `getLargestPoolSize` values are constantly at 15 - This is as expected.

`getQueue().size()` is always 0 - so no tasks are getting queued.

`getActiveCount()` values are always between 1-2.

Why aren't the rest of the threads in the pool working ?

Is "`getActiveCount()`-Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks." the right API to use ?

Answer (score 2):

As @Thomas suggests, the pool is creating threads as required so if you only give the pool 1-2 tasks to do at once, it will only have 1-2 threads active.  You need to feed more tasks to it at once if you want it to be busier.

Comment: Every incoming request, adds 7 tasks in a tight loop.

Comment: Unless your tasks are non-trivial it may not create new threads.  What do you see if you getActive() immediately after this tight loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java's thread pool that well but generally you'd only create as many threads as your machine has cores (or hardware threads) available. If you are running on a dual core machine 2 active threads are a sensible value.

Comment: This is not at all true.  For example, if you are hitting a slow external service, for example a rest API, then you could easily support many more threads than the number of available cores.

Comment: Yes, my 7 tasks are actually 7 external service calls. So i'd  guess while threads are blocked on I/O ( network in my case), it should process more threads. But seems like it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run this in debug mode in eclipse? It usually shows all the threads allocated as well as their statuses. 
I suspect that in your case the following scenario takes place: you have thread pool and thread pool has allocated number of threads to process the tasks you are submitting into it. But once any particular thread in the thread pool has completed the task submitted into the thread pool it does not terminate. Instead it switches its status to BLOCKED or WAITING (I don't remember for sure which one of them) and waits until the next task is passed into this particular thread for processing.